# Cross-platform WinForms app with Awesomium

Tags: c#, winforms, mono, awesomium

Do I need to use Awesomium.Mono if I want to create WinForms app with Awesomium and after that port it on Linux and OS X(using Mono)? Will I have a problems with the porting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use Awesomium.Mono if you want to run your application on other OS X or Linux. Some stuff does look different on other platforms, so the platform specific logic varies. But after all it should not be a problem. Have a look at the awesomium sample code.